# need string or buffer, file found

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-storm

I should keep a offset into the file and read that offset line and emit, update offset = offset + 1

```
class SimSpout(storm.Spout):

  # Not much to do here for such a basic spout
  def initialize(self, conf, context):
    ## Open the file with read only permit
    self.f = open('data.txt', 'r')
    ## Read the first line
    self._conf = conf
    self._context = context
    self._offset = 0
    storm.logInfo("Spout instance starting...")

 # Process the next tuple
 def nextTuple(self):
    # check if it reach at the EOF to close it
    with open(self.f) as f:
      f.readlines()[self._offset]
      #Emit a random sentence
      storm.logInfo("Emiting %s" % line)
      storm.emit([line])
    self._offset = self._offset + 1
```

but i got error

```
with open(self.f) as f:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

Answer (score 0):

You are opening a file in this line

```
self.f = open('data.txt', 'r')
```

and trying to open the file handle instead of the same file in this line

```
with open(self.f) as f:
```

Instead, in  `nextTuple`, just use `self.f` instead of `f`

Comment: thanks for replying , but excuse me i'm new to python . you mean write like that with open(self.f):
       self.f.readlines()[self._offset] ?

Comment: are you still here ?